# MAVEN implementation of SLF4J and LOG4J ; app

Tags: java, maven, logging, log4j, slf4j

I checked this question :
[SLF4J and Log4j 2 binding Maven dependency](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19012994/slf4j-and-log4j-2-binding-maven-dependency)

it seems that I've a simular problem.

But they use : *log4j-slf4j-impl* and I use *slf4j-log4j* 
(see pom.xml)

*conform :* [documentation SLF4J  - binding LOG4J](http://www.slf4j.org/manual.html#swapping)

[image: source]

[NETBEANS]

---

This is the class '**TestLogger**' and uses SLF4J:

```
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

public class TestLogger {

private static Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(TestLogger.class);

public static String name = "World";

public static void main(String[] args) {   
    logger.info("Hello {}", name);
    System.out.println("Test");
}
}
```

I get these errors from LOG4J (so the binding seems to be okay) :

```
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (TestLogger).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.
```

In this project in class '**TestLogger**' there is a binding between SLF4J and LOG4J, because the **errors are caused by LOG4J and we import SLF4J**.

pom.xml [only dependencies part]:

```
    <!--
        slf4j-api   - local
        slf4j-log4  - local
        log4j
    -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.12</version>
        <type>jar</type>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.17</version>
        <type>zip</type>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.12</version>
    </dependency>
```

[image: dependencies]

this is the **log4j.properties** file, this file worked well without MAVEN (in an other project with the same classes)

**log4j.properties**  is situated in the default package.

```
# Root logger option
log4j.rootLogger=INFO, stdout, file
# Direct log messages to stdout
# Redirect log messages to console
log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.stdout.Target=System.out
log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=[%-5p]  %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} - %c{10}, line %L  -  [%10.10t]%n >> %m%n
# Redirect log messages to a log file, support file rolling.
log4j.appender.file=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.file.File=log4j-homeauto.log
log4j.appender.file.MaxFileSize=5MB
log4j.appender.file.MaxBackupIndex=10
log4j.appender.file.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.file.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} [%-5p]  %30.30c %L - %m%n
```

*To be honest to problem is **not** clear to me*, but after reading the feedback on line I added also a **log4j.xml** in the default package.
In the hope this would solve my problem.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE log4j:configuration SYSTEM "log4j.dtd">

    <log4j:configuration xmlns:log4j="http://jakarta.apache.org/log4j/">
    <appender name="console" class="org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender"> 
    <param name="Target" value="System.out"/> 
    <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout"> 
      <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%-5p %c{1} - %m%n"/> 
    </layout> 
  </appender> 

  <appender name="LOG" class="org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender"> 
    <param name="file" value="example.log"/>
    <param name="MaxFileSize" value="100KB"/>
    <!-- Keep one backup file -->
    <param name="MaxBackupIndex" value="1"/> 
    <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout"> 
      <!-- Pattern to output the caller's file name and line number -->
      <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%5p [%t] (%F:%L) - %m%n"/> 
    </layout> 
  </appender>

</log4j:configuration>
  <root> 
    <priority value ="debug" /> 
    <appender-ref ref="console" />
    <appender-ref ref="LOG" />  
  </root>

</log4j:configuration>
```

---

---

---

Like I already said, I used this class also in other project without MAVEN and there it worked fine.
As an other test I created a class **TestLoggerLOG4J** in both projects
LOG4J seems to work different in MAVEN ... it doesn't find **neither** the properties, **neither** xml file
(I don't know which one is needed without MAVEN, the properties file was fine)

```
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;


public class TestLoggerLOG4J {

static Logger log = Logger.getLogger("file");

    public static String name = "World";

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        log.info("This is a test {}");
        System.out.println("Test");

    }

}
```

---

** s  o  l  u  t  i  o  n **

---

Thanks to  ** @Tunaki **

You need to place this file inside src/main/resources

I did this via the command line (linux terminal), and finally I found it back in my project.

Is there an other way? Do you maybe have a solution to avoid such problems?
Why doesn't MAVEN do that?

[image]

Comment: I'm not sure what your problem is or what it is you are asking, could you clarify?

Comment: @Tunaki, sorry that I'm not clear.

LOG4J (with SLF4J) in **MAVEN** doesn't find appender defined in the _LOG4J.properties_ / _LOG4J.xml_ file.

ERROR : 
**log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (TestLogger).**

Comment: OK. You need to place this file inside src/main/resources

Comment: @Tunaki **Thanks**
See the last part of the question, how can I avoid this things. Or make it happen automatically in the future projects.

Thks

Comment: "Why doesn't MAVEN do that?". Why doesn't Maven do what? Place correctly each file in your project?

Comment: @Tunaki :
when compiling and building ...
copy also the properties-file from _src/main/java/_ to _src/main/resources_

Comment: because the log4j properties file is a resource, not a (java) source. So maven expects it to find it in src/main/resources in order to copy it to the correct location (target/classes/) during the build.

Comment: @YiannisDermitzakis Thanks for the info, I had an other but same kind of problem ... now I copy it always to the working directory, and check it in java `System.getProperty("user.dir")` ....